# HTML5 player shows on webpage but, mp3 sound not playing

Tags: python, django, audio, mp3, html5-audio

I'm new to programming, I'm trying to put up a mp3 file and player on a django web page the player is showing but, the song is not playing.

```
**models.py** 

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    audio_file = models.FileField('media/')

**audio.html**
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="JesusChrist.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>

**media folder**
JesusChrist.mp3

**Settings.py**

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'firegod/static/media')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Check this out [Simple Is Better Than Complex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html)

Comment: Yeah I looked at it but, still having issues

Answer (score 0):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQJRwWpP8hs) is a great reference, and should spell everything out. He shows where files go when they are uploaded and how to access them in the templates.

Another problem you have is this:

```py
# Sets STATIC_ROOT
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
# Sets STATIC_URL
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Overwrites STATIC_ROOT
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
# Overwrites STATIC_URL
STATIC_URL = '/media/'
```

I believe what you want is:

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and then you should be able to find your file at
`src="media/audio.mp3"`. If you need to, `print` the url of the uploaded file so you know where to find it.

I am about to dive into this, so I might be a little off, though I know the video linked above was very beneficial.